# 502 error when Serverless image handler requests a large file size

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, thumbor

I've deployed the AWS Cloud formation [Serverless image handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/serverless-image-handler/template.html) to resize images in an S3 bucket which is working well. It is using Cloudfront, API Gateway, Lamdba, and a custom domain.

My original images (PNGs) are of a reasonable size (~5MB or ~5000px across) and my derivatives are of various sizes. Up until about `fit-in/2048x2048` everything works well. Above that though I get a 502 "Internal server error".

I've tried maxing out memory and timeouts to no avail. Does anyone have any idea what's going on there? Is there some invisible limit?

```
{
    "message": "Internal server error"
}
```

Comment: What do the logs in CloudWatch logs say?

Comment: CloudWatch doesn't even create a line item when this error is caused. It does log on success however with smaller images.

Comment: Does AWS Lambda log at least the generic START, END and REPORT lines for the invocation in CloudWatch?

Comment: For the ones that fail absolutely nothing is written to the log.

Comment: In that case you should consult the AWS Support, as it's probably a problem deep down in AWS Lambda internals.

Comment: @Queenvictoria have you found the culprit at the end? And what was your solution?

Comment: So, as @kannaiyan says, Lambda isn't able to return such large files. [This link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) is actually the correct one in this case. Invocation payload (request and, importantly, response) is limited to 6MB in total.

The fix, which if you think about it is the Right Way, is to perform the resize, return the image to S3 (which is what I was doing anyway), and then redirect to the resized version on S3. It's a bit tricky with timings, infinite loops, and CloudFront caches, but you'll get there in the end.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is caused by the payload limit of **6mb** for Lambda Functions. As a workaround it is possible to save the images directly to a output bucket and deliver them from this bucket to the customer.

The issue is in the future backlog since 07/2018 ([see here](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-handler/issues/35) or [here](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-image-handler/issues/97))

Answer (score 0):

The architecture may need a correction here. Whenever you deliver large files, you need to leave the responsibility to S3 / CloudFront. Lambda should take care of authenticating / authorization of the content.

API Gateway has a limitation on the lambda response limit.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/limits.html

Comment: Sorry which lambda limit do you think is throttling the image size? Are you saying that the AWS CloudFormation package is incapable of delivering large files?